# Context Path and static content | Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to port my application to Spring boot and things are working fine for me. I am facing issue with static content and contextPath. I have added following property in my `application.properties`

```
server.contextPath=/sm-admin
```

before this, I was referring to my static contents by

```
<script src="/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but with addition of `contextPath`, above configuration is no longer working and I have following way

Change static content references to

```
 <script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or

I believe there should be some way to handle it using application.properties file but I am unable to find such configuration. Can some on point me to right direction.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 factors in this problem: your web app and the browser, so I don't think this can be controlled through Spring since this has to do with the browser's behavior.

**Problem**

In your 'old' html file version your app root context was `/`. That's why `src='/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'` loaded without any issues.

Now since your app root context was changed to `/sm-admin` your web app will serve only request prefixed with that path. That's why `src='/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'` doesn't work, your server will have responded fine if the it were `src='/sm-admin/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'`

Now `src='../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'` is working b/c your page must have been served from 1 folder below the root context, ie: `/sm-admin/page/mypage.html` and with `..` you are just referencing the root path indirectly.

**My proposed solutions:**

1. Prefix all resources loaded from the root with `/sm-admin`.

**Or**

2. Change all absolute paths to relatives path, ie: change `src='/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'` to `src='plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'` and set the base url in your header for all your relatives path, ie: `<base href="/sm-admin/"/>`. One caveat of this solution is that anywhere in your app you are using relative paths they'll become relative to this base path.

Comment: Agree and I am ok to go ahead with either approach, I was looking if spring boot have a way to handle context for static contents

Comment: Yeah, it'll be a nice feature, but imagine how spring would handle it, either have to scan you resources and fix them dynamically or it has to arbitrarily reroute your root requests.

Answer (score 2):

In your index.html, change `<base href="/">` to **`<base href="./">`**.

This solved my problem.

Comment: This was the solution.